# Apple guidelines for financial application security

Tags: iphone, security, authentication, standards, finance

I have read the secure coding guide provided by Apple. I am looking at developing a financial application. What are the best methods to authenticate the user? Are there any specific guidelines for finance applications (relating to security) given by Apple?

Comment: This is an open ended question, but there are some basic rules you should research thoroughly before starting. [Here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/webauth%3asec10.pdf) is a authentication white paper that gives some examples of poor security authentication for sensitive user identification.

Answer (score 0):

Just generic wisdom:

Don't store the password in plain text.  Although the typical user can't access files inside of an iPhone, a jailbroken iPhone has full root access and will be able to peer inside the bundle, and can easily read a plain text file called "userPass.txt."  Instead, use the iPhone's keychain to store logins and passwords.

As evidenced by PayPal's iOS security blunder that just happened, be sure to use a secure HTTPS connection when authenticating to a server.  Someone packet sniffing on an open WiFi network is able to exploit the current iOS PayPal app and get credentials out of the air.

Comment: Did that changed ? Paypal API is safe now ?